# Triggering approach for an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting a value to input box and trigger to hear the change. I would also like to always hear the input change, and for that I made this function.

Can any expert please verify the way I did is correct? Or is it further tune-able?

```
var page = function () {
    return {
        init : function () {
            var input = $("#pNo");
            $(document).on("pageChange", this.onPageChange.bind(this));
            $(input).val(1).trigger({type:'pageChange',element:input});
            $(input).bind("change paste keyup",function() { $.event.trigger({type: "pageChange", element:input})});
        },

        onPageChange : function (e) {
            console.log($(e.element).val());
        }
    }
}();

page.init();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jyfgw7L/1/)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to reduce the code:

```
var page = {
  init: function(selector) {
    $(selector).on('change paste keyup', page.onPageChange);
  },
  onPageChange: function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).val());
  }
};

page.init('#pNo');
```